# Entity Framework Bulk Insert Related Entity

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext

How to handle fast bulk insert of an entity with a bulk of related entity and maintain relationship. For example I need to insert 1 Person that has 50,000 Records.

Comment: There is [bulk-insert library](https://entityframework-extensions.net/bulk-insert). But you should insert Person at first and then Records with appropriate FKs mapped to Person.Id

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

This library is not free but allows to bulk insert entities. You can also include related entities with the `IncludeGraph` options.

You can find an online example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/spN4T5

```
// IncludeGraph: The IncludeGraph option allows to INSERT/UPDATE/MERGE entities by including the child entities graph.
using (var context = new EntityContext())
{
    context.BulkInsert(list, options => options.IncludeGraph = true);
}
```